# Is there a way to survive outside the town walls overnight in Die2Nite?

Tags: die2nite

I ask because in the Help for the "Last Man Standing" section, it says:

> The town can not have been devastated
>   on a previous attack (a town is
>   devastated if a night passes and there
>   are no citizens within the town
>   walls.).

That makes it sound like it's possible for people to survive outside, but I've never seen it happen or read anything about someone surviving out there. Anyone know if it's possible?

Update: The answer was "no" when this question was asked during Season 1. For Season 2 and beyond, the answer is "Yes".

Comment: Season 2 started...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Season 2 — we can now camp outside.

Answer (score 6):

From what I understand, at some point in the future there will be some way to camp outside the town.

You can see a few hints of that in game already. One example is the ability to tag squares as suitable for camping.

At this point in time though, there is no way to survive outside of town through the night.

Comment: Season 2 started...

Comment: This answer was correct when the question was originally asked in Season 1, but as of Season 2 the answer is now "yes", so I'm moving the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

From what I've seen, everyone outside at midnight will inevitably die.

Comment: Season 2 started...

Answer (score -1):

I found something (barricade maybe) while scavenging in the desert and it gave me the option to deploy it as a fortification (or something similar).  I didn't try it and haven't read up on it, but it might be related.

Comment: I don't think it's related, but I admit I don't know what installing defenses outside is supposed to do.

Comment: It doesn't do anything at the moment.  I've just tried it.  Nothing happened.

Comment: Season 2 started...