# Staying outside during the night

Tags: die2nite

Is it possible to survive outside the town during the night if my character is stuck (due to the lack of AP) on a square that has 0 zombies on it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12190/is-there-a-way-to-survive-outside-the-town-walls-overnight-in-die2nite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If your character is not inside the town when the zombies attack, you die.

Comment: Would you like to update this answer with the season 2 info?

Comment: @Arkive I'm busy cringing at the idea of how much D2N stuff I have to update...I'll get to it sometime soon.